# How to deploy this mongodb cluster?

Tags: database, mongodb, deployment

So I have been trying to deploy a mongodb replica sets. My goal is to have one vps running all mongodb instances required on docker. I have been following this [GitHub](https://github.com/minhhungit/mongodb-cluster-docker-compose) and It has been smooth so far. Now my question is how do I setup authentication for this so my servers and Robo 3t client can connect to it a url something like this

> mongodb+srv://username:password@serverurl.com/databasename?retryWrites=true&w=majority

Do I need to expose only the router instance or do I need to expose everything? and How? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to enable authentication/authorization at mongodb cluster level :
   https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-internal-authentication/
   ( you may need to enable transport encryption )

2.You need to expose only the routing service (mongos) ...
how to publish / expose : https://www.whitesourcesoftware.com/free-developer-tools/blog/docker-expose-port/